# Create train test split by group

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a data frame which I would like to split into a train and test set by group ID. The following code samples random rows and puts them into a train and test df:

```
samp <- sample(nrow(df), 0.7 * nrow(df))
train <- df[samp, ]
test <- df[-samp, ]
```

However, I would like to keep my IDs grouped together.

Example input df:

```
my_dat <- data.frame(ID=as.factor(rep(1:3, each = 3)), Var=sample(1:100, 9))

  ID Var
  1  17
  1  26
  1 100
  2   9
  2  41
  2  49
  3  36
  3  18
  3   5
```

And desired output to:

Train:

```
  ID Var
  1  17
  1  26
  1 100
  3  36
  3  18
  3   5
```

Test:

```
  ID Var
  2   9
  2  41
  2  49
```

Comment: Then just sample the ids. something like `myIds <- unique(df$id); myTrainers <- sample(myIds, 2)`. and then `myTesters <- myIds[!(myIds %in% myTrainers)]`.

Comment: Thank you. However there seems to be something wrong. The output of `myTrainers ` and `myTesters ` are respectively: `[1] 2 3
Levels: 1 2 3` and `[1] 1
Levels: 1 2 3`.

Comment: Your variable is a factor variable. This is what the "Levels: 1 2 3" indicates. If you notice the first portions, you can see that the task was accomplished, with myTrainers getting ids 2 and 3 and myTesters getting id 1. To transform the id into an integer, you could use `as.integer`, but you might want to look closer at that variable and why it was read-in as a factor variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do this using `dplyr`:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create more data to better demonstrate grouping effect
my_dat <-
  data.frame(ID = as.factor(rep(1:3, each = 9)), Var = sample(1:100, 27))

# Randomly assign train/test groups to all values of ID
groups <-
  my_dat %>%
  select(ID) %>%
  distinct(ID) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(group = sample(
    c("train", "test"),
    1,
    replace = TRUE,
    prob = c(0.5, 0.5) # Set weights for each group here
  ))

groups

# Join group assignments to my_dat
my_dat <- my_dat %>%
  left_join(groups)

my_dat
```

This approach leaves your original data intact but adds a new column defining the group (train vs test) for each row. If you want to get a dataframe with only training data, you can filter it like this:

```
filter(my_dat, group == "train")
```

Comment: Thank you. When I execute the code, the new column (`group`) is filled with only `test.` There is no `training.`

Comment: That's odd, @apples-oranges. Have you tried running it repeatedly? Because there are only three groups and two possible values, you'll get only one result 1/4 of the time that you run the code.

Comment: I ran it three times then the column was filled with `test`. The fourth time I ran it, last column was filled with `train`.

Comment: When I `set.seed(327)` I see values for `groups$group` of train, train, and test. Is this what you see?

Comment: Hmmm, groups$group is all filled with `train`

Comment: When's the last time you updated `dplyr`? There have been a few breaking changes lately. I just re-installed `dplyr` and `tidyverse` and my code is still running properly. I was getting the same problem you describe until I added `rowwise()`, which did not exist in its current form until June of last year.

Comment: That was it! I have another question if you don't mind. How can I specify the ratio between training and test split. My real data frame is 2.8 million rows, and it seems that the code cuts it in half.

Comment: I just edited my answer to include probability weighting. Change the two values for `prob` to whatever you want the percentages to be for train and test.